# Insert a new item into listview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview

When I click a button, I am trying to insert a new listview item.

It is supposed to go in a certain Group, and it will have an item, followed by two subitems. But my code isn't working.

```
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(itemtext, grouptext);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(subitem1);
            lvi.SubItems.Add(subitem2);
            lvi.ToolTipText = subitem1;
            items.Items.Add(lvi);
```

Can someone please help me out?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by `It's not working.`? does it not add the item to `ListView` or it adds the item to `ListView` but does not add it to specific group? And I don't see any group assignment in your code!

Comment: grouptext is where i tell it what group to put it in. (the groups already exist). And no, it just adds the item to a NEW group called Default.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The overload of the ListViewItem constructor that you are using (string, string) is for the item text and the imageKey. You should be able to assign your item to the proper group by using the constructor overload that uses (string, ListViewGroup).

Something like this:

```
     ListViewGroup myGroup = items.Groups[0];
     ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(itemtext, myGroup);
```